# Wrapping an object inside another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have the following object:

```
var arr ={
{"id":{"id":"1059","department_id":4476,"location_id":42}},
{"id":"1060","department_id":75,"location_id":42}},
{"id":"178","department_id":75,"location_id":42}
};
```

I need to wrap this in a parent object, to make the following:

```
var new_arr = 
 employees: {[
{"id":{"id":"1059","department_id":4476,"location_id":42}},
{"id":"1060","department_id":75,"location_id":42}},
{"id":"178","department_id":75,"location_id":42}
]};
```

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: Both samples contain syntax error.

Comment: `new_arr = {employees:[arr]} `

Comment: The errors in your code it make it impossible to work out what you need. Also, if you add in the code you've already tried we might be able to work it out from that.

Comment: @gurvinder372, pretty sure the OP needs to understand the differences between objects and arrays first. That example isn't really going to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean

```
var arr =[
{"id":{"id":"1059","department_id":4476,"location_id":42}},
{"id":{"id":"1060","department_id":75,"location_id":42}},
{"id":{"id":"178","department_id":75,"location_id":42}}
];

var employees = {employees:arr};

console.log(employees);
```

?